# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests' in PyCharm

Tags: python, pip, python-requests

I have a python code in PyCharm in which i am using
import requests
but the terminal is showing me the following error:

(venv) ahmad@Ahmad:~/Desktop/Spiders$ python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in 
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

But I have installed pip and requests as well.

Answer (score 8):

you can use this :

just go to file > sitting > project : name > project interpreter > add > search and install

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing you have not set your interpreter or installed the necessary packages in the interpreter in PyCharm.

- Can you check in your  `File -> Settings`
- There, on the side panel, you can open your **Project: <*project_name*>** and check **Project Interpreter**
- This will show the interpreter and the installed packages which you can use.

If the interpreter is empty, you need to add it.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can just found the icon of **Search** in right highest corner and search for 'import modules'. Then click on "**Project:** [YOUR_PROJECT]" choose '**Python Interpreter**' and then click on 'plus' button. Thus you can install 'requests' module manually.

(Some sites say that you can call **Search** by pressing Alt + Enter, but it doesn`t work in my case)

Answer (score 0):

I had to go to the CLi (command line) and run ">pip install requests" - this after trying unsuccessfully from the Pycharm 'Setting/Interpreter' gui menu.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the ...

**settings > [projectname] > python interpreter > add interpreter**

...steps described in other answers here. I got the location of the 'requests' install I knew I'd successfully completed by going back to the terminal, and using

**pip install requests**

again, and taking note of the install filepath from the 'Requirement already satisfied' output. Used that in the 'Settings...' step above, and voila!

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps if you are using  IntelliJ

Go to

```
Project structure -> Click SDKs -> Click Packages TAB -> 
Click '+' Sign -> Available packages screen shows -> In search box type name of package -> Select it and click 'Install Package"
```