# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'

Tags: python, pycharm, ide

I am new to PyCharm (coming from RStudio world). I am just trying to setup a PyCharm project. My first line of code is `google` library import (Later I intend to write codes for pulling data from BigQuery).

But I am getting an error saying `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'` in PyCharm. I tried suggested solutions for a very [similar stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57212573/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-requests-in-pycharm).
I also tried `invalidating cache and restart` by doing File >

I can see that the `google` is installed in the Python interpreter. I am not able to figure out what's the issue. To me looks like it is related to the way we setup environment in PyCharm.

Edit: I checked Project interpreter and Run Configuration interpreter. Both match and still get the same thing.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you click on google in Pycharm and then the red lightbulb in the margin does it give you the option to install the google package to the project? Pycharm is precious about doing this as well as just having the pip package installed.

Comment: There is a difference between the project interpreter and the run configuration interpreter. Next to the play/debug buttons, press the drop down button and press edit configuration and make sure your run configuration interpreter matches the correct interpreter

Comment: @TomMcLean: Both project interpreter and the run configuration interpreter match.

Answer (score 0):

The library you want to use is not named `google`, is called `google-cloud-bigquery`, just install that one.

Look here:
https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/bigquery/latest#windows

I guess you know, but you can install it with pip (like in the above link) or in Pycharm settings (clicking in the + in your third screenshot).

Comment: That didn't work either